# Prove that if $(||f_n||)$ is bounded and $(f_n(x))$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{K}$ for all $x\in E $ then $f_n \rightarrow f$ in the weak$^*$-sense

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, cauchy-sequences

I'm preparing for my exam in functional analysis and I'm trying to solve the following question:

Let X be a Banach space, let E$\subset$X be dense and let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $X^*$*. Prove that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in the weak$^*$-sense if and only if $(||f_n||)$ is bounded and $(f_n(x))$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{K}$ for all $x\in E$.

I have proven the ($\rightarrow$) direction, but I don't know how to do the ($\leftarrow$) direction. I know I need to show that $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x\in X$ so I'm trying to apply the triangle inequality in some way but I can't seem to get it work.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess there are typos: $f_n\in X^*$ and $f_n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence for $x\in E.$ In order to prove in the opposite direction by density of $E$ the sequence $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy for $x\in X.$ Just use $$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\le |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f_n(y)-f_m(y)|+|f_m(y)-f_m(x)|\\ \le 2c\|x-y\|+|f_n(y)-f_m(y)|$$ where $ y\in E$ and $c$ is a bound of $\|f_n\|.$

Comment: Thank you, there were typos indeed,  I edited the post. Why does $(f_n(x))$ being Cauchy imply that $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x\in X$?

Comment: Banach-Alaoglu implies that any bounded set $\{f:|f|\le R\}$ is weak*-compact. Now, you can show the result by showing that every subsequence in $\{f_{n_k}(x)\}$ has a further subsequence $\{f_{n_{k_j}}\}$ that converges a limit $f$. Notice that due to the conditions of $\{f_{n}(x)\}$ being Cauchy, we get that $f$ does not depend on the first subsequence  $\{f_{n_k}\}$ we chose.

Comment: Being Cauchy implies convergence in any complete metric space, that is the definition of complete space. Notice that $f_n(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, which is a complete space.